# Where to ask for translation of scientific/technological terms?

Tags: resources

I am still a *komencanto*, and I am always looking for translations of specialised terminology I encounter. Quite often, I manage to find a satisfactory solution by myself, thanks to the power of *kunmetaĵoj*. But sometimes not.

For computer-related terms, [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net) is very helpful. But otherwise, the availability of resources really depends on the field. So, in case I do not find anything, are there fora or mailing lists to ask for a translation?

Or maybe this SE site is just the right place for that.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which area of specialization you're interested in, you might check with UEA to see if they have a *fakdelegito* in that area of specialization that you could ask. Otherwise, I would ask here. For more specialized questions, it might take more time for a good answer to bubble up, but it has worked here before.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use Wikipedia: open the page about the particular phenomenon in my native language and then see if there is an Esperanto-version. To my astonishment, the answer is more often yes than no. This might not be the most correct way to go but I simply trust and/or hope that the users there are qualified enough to write about the topics. If someone googles the word I used they are likely to end up in the very same Vikipedio-page and may then backtrack to their own native language.

Comment: I often use Wikipedia that way with other languages. With Esperanto, it does not work so well, but it is still a thing to check first.

Comment: Note that the original question was where to ASK a question. You don't generally use Wikipedia to ask questions. Wikipedia is a good tool, but it's not a definitive source for information.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander You're right, I didn't pay attention to the *ask*-part. What about komputeko, by the way? I'm not very familiar with it but I thought that was also more of a "read and search"-tool than a forum to ask question.

Comment: I understood his question to be "where can I ask once I've exhausted all the means at my own disposal - including Komputeko" -- but I could have misunderstood.